# "The provided key element does not match the schema" when updating a nested array in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple React/Node app that creates tasks and I'd like to be able to add notes to each task. I can successfully add and delete tasks, but I'm having trouble adding a new note to a task.

My database schema in DynamoDB looks like this:

```
{
"taskId": "e3b8d901-6d74-4caa-9360-5b2f7aaec513",
"notes": [
    {
        "noteId": "aeeeeb60-3221-4d4e-b362-d63b48f42fba",
        "text": "thing to do next and words",
        "status": "TODO"
    }
],
"title": "Some Task"
```

}

This is how I'm trying to add a new note to the notes array:

```
function createNote(newNote){
  if (!newNote) {
    throw new Error('Missing newNote information')
  }
  return docClient.update({
    TableName: 'tasks',
    Key: {
      'taskId': newNote.taskId
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #notes = list_append(#notes, :notes)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#notes': 'notes'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':notes': [
        {
          'noteId': uuid(),
          'text': newNote.text,
          'status': 'TEMP'
        }
      ]
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
  }).promise()
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('Task updated!', res)
      return res
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Task not updated', error);
      throw error
    })
}
```

When I try add a new note, I get the error message:
"The provided key element does not match the schema"

I got the idea to use list_append from this post here: [How do I update nested list data in dynamodb using document client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254867/how-do-i-update-nested-list-data-in-dynamodb-using-document-client)

Edit to add: I've also tried reading the documentation here, but I don't understand how the example (with all the --'s) applies to my code: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.AddingListElements

Is there something wrong with my syntax here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had a mismatch in my api.put and my createNote function. In api.put I was passing two parameters (query id and request body), but CreateNote was only accepting one parameter.